# html to php redirect

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, redirect

Подскажите пожалуйста. Как с одного домена с файлами html, настроить переадресацию на другой, с форматом файлов php. Допустим, site.com/poleznii-sovet.html > site.net/poleznii-sovet.php... Спасибо!